# Setting the value of slider widget, nothing happens

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-slider

I am trying to set the value of a slider using a JavaScript after the slider has already been created and had it's value set.

I make the slider and it's text label:

```
    $("#maxDegradationSlider").slider({
    range: "min",
    value: 62,
    min: 0,
    max: 100,
    step: .25,
    slide: function (event, ui) {
        $("#maxDegradation").text(ui.value + "%");
    }
});
$("#maxDegradation").text($("#maxDegradationSlider").slider("value") + "%");
```

Then I have tried to reset the value with the following methods both of which do nothing:

```
$("maxDegradationSlider").val(50);
```

I also tried:

```
$("maxDegradationSlider").slider("option", "value", 50);
```

The bigger picture is for me to set the value from a C# class.

Comment: `$("maxDegradationSlider") != $("#maxDegradationSlider")`

Comment: I see that now, but unfortunately, fixing this still will not let me set the slider value to 50 strangely. I am doing `$("#maxDegradationSlider").val(50);` directly after creating the slider.

Comment: @JohnAugust Any errors in the console?

Comment: Let me check, I was using IE, with chrome I am seeing `no element found` The (`#`) has been corrected, but it is still saying that. This is my command copy and pasted: `$("#maxDegradationSlider").val(50);` I also tried the other way: `$("maxDegradationSlider").slider("option", "value", 50);`

Comment: @JohnAugust Okay, so it seems the slider element doesn't go by that name? Can you inspect the DOM and investigate what you see?

Comment: I am not 100% sure is this is what we are looking for, but I see an: `id:"maxDegradationSlider"`  along with a `className:"ui-slider-handle ui-state-default ui-corner-all"` and if I change this HTML: `<a style="left: 62%;" class="ui-slider-handle ui-state-default ui-corner-all" href="#"></a>` i can directly control the slider value to whatever I want.

Comment: Okay, I really cannot explain this, but I rebuilt and now it is magically working. I have no idea why. This is the code: `$("#maxDegradationSlider").slider("option", "value", 10);` (also, I had fixed the missing hash tag a while ago even in my comment 3 posts up.)

Comment: @JohnAugust Fantastic, glad it worked out for ya!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you missed an id sign (`#`) before the name of your element:

```
$('#maxDegradationSlider')
   ^
   missing
```